# How to read json file? (for variable...)

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

### I read json file. However, variables have been brought in this way.

```
df = spark.read.json("simulation_data_x.json")
df
DataFrame[V1: double, V10: double, V100: double, V11: double, V12: double, V13: double, V14: double, V15: double, V16: double, V17: double, V18: double, V19: double, V2: double, V20: double, V21: double, V22: double, V23: double, V24: double, V25: double, V26: double, V27: double, V28: double, V29: double, V3: double, V30: double, V31: double, V32: double, V33: double, V34: double, V35: double, V36: double, V37: double, V38: double, V39: double, V4: double, V40: double, V41: double, V42: double, V43: double, V44: double, V45: double, V46: double, V47: double, V48: double, V49: double, V5: double, V50: double, V51: double, V52: double, V53: double, V54: double, V55: double, V56: double, V57: double, V58: double, V59: double, V6: double, V60: double, V61: double, V62: double, V63: double, V64: double, V65: double, V66: double, V67: double, V68: double, V69: double, V7: double, V70: double, V71: double, V72: double, V73: double, V74: double, V75: double, V76: double, V77: double, V78: double, V79: double, V8: double, V80: double, V81: double, V82: double, V83: double, V84: double, V85: double, V86: double, V87: double, V88: double, V89: double, V9: double, V90: double, V91: double, V92: double, V93: double, V94: double, V95: double, V96: double, V97: double, V98: double, V99: double]
```

### I want to change or bring in variables in this way,

```
DataFrame[V1 : double, V2 : double, V3 : double....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define **`schema`** using **`StructType`** and read the json file using schema option

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sch=StructType([StructField('v1',DoubleType()),StructField('v2',DoubleType())])

#read the json file using schema    
df = spark.read.schema(sch).json("simulation_data_x.json")
```